# Upload a file to sharepoint using postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook-restapi

I'm facing below error when I try to upload a file to sharepoint using access token.

```
x-msdavext_error →917656;
Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
```

I have given app permission request as follows:

```
AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
```

And I have followed the steps mentioned in below post:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250827/download-and-upload-file-from-share-point-using-java-rest-api-call.

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the body to binary in Postman, check the similar thread as below.

[Upload file to SharePoint online with HTTP REST calls](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253430/upload-file-to-sharepoint-online-with-http-rest-calls)

And refer to SharePoint REST API article here:

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)